# configparser - create file with key and no value

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I have to create an ini file similar to this :

```
[rke2_servers]
host0 
host1 
host2 

[rke2_agents]
host4
host5
host6

[rke2_cluster:children]
rke2_servers
rke2_agents
```

I tried to create the file using this code:

```
import configparser
def initfile(rke2s, rke2a, filepath):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    config['rke2_servers'] = {rke2s: ''}
    config['rke2_agents'] = {rke2a: ''}
    config['rke2_cluster:children'] = {'rke2_servers':'', 'rke2_agents':''}
    with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

but the result is this:

```
[rke2_servers]
host0 = 

[rke2_agents]
host1 = 

[rke2_cluster:children]
rke2_servers = 
rke2_agents =
```

The problem is that it keeps the "=" after every key

As a solution I can always clean the file after creation and remove any trailing =, but there should be a way to keep an empty key in configparser, but there is no documentation about it.

Comment: It's [not valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Keys_(properties)). Why do you want an invalid ini file?

Comment: What if you set those values to `None` instead of an empty string?

Comment: https://github.com/rancherfederal/rke2-ansible/blob/main/inventory/sample/hosts.ini 
It is a requirement for the ansible inventory creation

Comment: @nofinator that did it, thank you very much !

   `config['rke2_servers'] = {rke2s: None}`, post an answer and i'll accept it. Thank you !

Comment: FYI for the other commenters, `ConfigParser` is documented as providing a structure *similar* to what’s found in Microsoft Windows INI files. (emphasis mine) There are many different examples that you normally wouldn't find in Windows [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure)

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot simpler to not use `configparser` at all here.

Comment: @nofinator, please post your answer so I can accept it and add working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `None` instead of an empty string:

```
def initfile(rke2s, rke2a, filepath):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    config['rke2_servers'] = {rke2s: None}
    config['rke2_agents'] = {rke2a: None}
    config['rke2_cluster:children'] = {'rke2_servers': None, 'rke2_agents': None}
    with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

FYI, ConfigParser is documented as providing a structure *similar* to what's found in Microsoft Windows INI files. (emphasis mine) So even though Windows requires values in INI files, it's ok to have empty values in config files in Python here.

In fact, there are [other examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure) that you normally wouldn't find in Windows.